# bring data in from i model to another - C# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Morning folks

I have an ID field that I want to pass from 1 we page to another.

EG - I want to pass and display the ID on another page, so that the user can see that these pages are linked.

Im using visual studio 2013 / MVC and C' to complete this task.

I have 2 separate models for the two pages that I have created.   I have a button on my first page that opens up the second form.  here is the code for the button:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Carer / Household", "Create", "CarerDetails", new { id = Model.client.id }, new { id = "Carer", @class = "btn btn-sm btn-warning" })
```

When I hover over my button, I can see the id that I want.

All I want to do is display this on my next page (even though, this is not part of the model for the second page).  I simply want to display to the user the id of the previous page as this is required.

On my second page, i have the following code and thought that this would pull in my id field.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.allClients.id)
```

As you can see the id field is sat in a model named allclients, the other model is named carer.

at the top of my web for for the second page i have 
    @model EDTSystem.Models.CarerViewModel.    This pulls in the carer data.  I have tried to connect to my allclients model by using a 
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.allClients.id).

This has failed to bring back the id from this model.

can anyone point me in the right direction?

regards
Betty

Answer (score 0):

I would just add an ID field to your second model and fill it according to your first model.

Another solution might be to store the ID in a `Session`. Use this code in your first view to fill the Session:

```
@Session["ID"] = Model.client.id
```

You can access this specific session from every view and every action you have. In your case:

```
@Html.Editor(Session["ID"])
```

Comment: Please don't rely on session for things like this, you should indeed add the ID field to your Strongly Typed model

Comment: @Milney Yes, adding an ID field is definitely the better and safer solution